# Developer setup install script, with Homebrew & Dropbox?

Tags: mac, homebrew, dropbox

Installing development tools is not too hard these days, with the likes of Homebrew - http://brew.sh ... So I thought I would try to write a script with the homebrew installation and various tools, which I could use whenever I set up a new Mac.

Some people have already done something like this, see some examples here: http://www.justinball.com/2011/12/03/script-your-development-environment-setup-on-your-new-mac/

But before I do this, I had another thought. Could I simply install, via Homebrew to a folder within my Dropbox... and then when I start using a new Mac, just install Dropbox on it and point my .zshrc  script to the folder .. to get the exact same developer environment?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why not simply use `git` (and [github](https://github.com) or [bitbucket](https://bitbucket.org))? I think that should work better for synchronizing/saving the dotfiles. See google and [various blogposts](http://blog.sanctum.geek.nz/managing-dot-files-with-git/) for detailed instructions, or search github directly ([1](https://github.com/ryanb/dotfiles)), ([2](https://github.com/rtomayko/dotfiles)).